# Why isn't this MySQL statement working?

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, phpmyadmin

I have a table `Seats` with the columns, `SeatID`, `Date`, `RouteID` and `Seats`. The primary key is `SeatsID`. The value of seats is 50, and I wish to subtract whatever the user has entered into `$tickettotal` from 50 and then insert the new value.

The user also has to enter which `RouteID` and `Date` they wish to travel. I want these to be inserted into the `Seats` table along with the new value of `Seats`.

If another user enters the same `Date` and `RouteID` then the `Seats` should be updated. Otherwise a new record should be inserted with `SeatID`, `Date`, `RouteID`, and the reduced value for `Seats`.

I thought this statement should do it but I keep getting errors back such as

```
Can't find string terminator '"' anywhere before EOF, although when i put " at the end of the statement i just get another syntax error line 108, near ""') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Seats=Seats-'"$tickettotal" .
```

---

**Update**

I now have it inserting fine, although on a duplicate entry of both `Date` and `RouteID` it doesn't update `Seats`: it still just inserts a new value. The `Seats - $tickettotal` isn't working either.

```
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO $Stable(Date,RouteID) 
VALUES ('$Tdate','$Rid') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Seats=Seats-'$tickettotal'");
```

**Update Answer**

Because i didn't have a unique column, I created one using both date and RouteID added together so.

```
$Tdate =~ s/-//gi;
$dateandrid = $Tdate . $Rid;
```

The first line removes the hyphens and the second puts them together. Then using these statements get the desired effect i wanted.

```
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO $Stable(RouteAndDate,Date,RouteID) VALUES    ('$dateandrid','$Tdate','$Rid') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Seats=Seats");
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO $Stable(RouteAndDate,Date,RouteID) VALUES ('$dateandrid','$Tdate','$Rid') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Seats=Seats-'$tickettotal'");
```

Comment: You need a close bracket at the end of the `do`.

Comment: $dbh->do("INSERT INTO $Stable(Date,RouteID,Seats) VALUES ('$Tdate','$Rid','$Tdate') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Seats=Seats-'$tickettotal'");

Comment: What database engine are you using? What is the primary key of the `Seats` table? Do you have any other `UNIQUE` constraints?

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin, The primary key of the seats table is just SeatsID, with an Auto increment, no

Comment: Are you certain that your defined quote char is the single quote.  it has been my experience that MYSQL likes to use backticks for quoting.  So I think you've got some over-quoting going on.  Listen the to  people telling you to use place holders.

Answer (score 1):

You must avoid SQL Injection with parameter binding:

```
$dbh->do( qq{
     INSERT INTO $Stable(Date, RouteID) 
     VALUES (?, ?)
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Seats=Seats-?
     },
     undef,
     $Tdate, $Rid, $tickettotal
);
```

Comment: `prepare` and `execute` is generally preferable to `do`